# HTTP POST request turned to GET on Azure App Service

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have two applications of which one is hosted in Azure App Service (.NET Framework 4.8) and exposes (among other things) two endpoints that receive POST requests:

Endpoint A:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> EndpointA([FromUri]Guid sessionId, [FromUri]Guid transactionId, [FromBody]ADataDTO data)
```

Endpoint B:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> EndpointB(Guid sessionId, Guid transactionId, [FromBody] BDataDTO data)
```

Both of these endpoints are called in a same way, by using HttpClient.PostAsync method:

```
 public async Task CallEndpointAAsync(string callbackUrl, ADataDTO data)
    {
        //... validations

        var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

        var jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, jsonSerializerSettings);
        var content = new StringContent(jsonObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        await httpClient.PostAsync(callbackUrl, content);
    }
```

and

```
public async Task CallEndpointBAsync(string callbackUrl, BDataDTO data)
    {
        //... validations

        var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

        var jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, jsonSerializerSettings);
        var content = new StringContent(jsonObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        await httpClient.PostAsync(callbackUrl, content);
    }
```

Now, locally both of these calls work perfectly, but when published to Azure App Service, call to EndpointB works and call to EndpointA does not.

After some investigation, I noticed that calls to EndpointA end up as GET instead of POST which should not be possible (let me point out that locally both work fine).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, after hours of investigating and trying everything that I could think of, I figured out the difference between these two calls and why my POST turns to GET.

For the EndpointA, on my test environment, callbackUrl was starting with http, while for EndpointB it starts with https.

Now, Azure App Service hosts the app with HTTPS only option, that (from the documentation) does this:

> By default, App Service forces a redirect from HTTP requests to HTTPS

Source: [Azure HTTPS Only option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-4039670#enforce-https)

Further down the line, HttpClient turns request to GET on redirect, and thus I got no data on my POST endpoint :)

I hope that this will save somebody some time :)

Comment: That solved my issue.. It was a real head scratcher. Thanks man!